# Azure New-AzureRmResource "Account Type" missing, but if I add it "Parameter not found"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to use New-AzureRmResource to create a new storage account.  But I am running into something that is baffling me.  My command is here:

```
New-AzureRmResource -Location "East US" -ResourceGroupName "myResGrp" -ResourceName "storagename" -ResourceType "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts" -Kind "Storage"
```

But this dumps the error

> New-AzureRmResource : AccountTypeMissing : The accountType field is
>   missing from the request.

So I add it in (tried both "AccountType" and "accountType"):

```
New-AzureRmResource -Location "East US" -ResourceGroupName "myResGrp" -ResourceName "storagename" -ResourceType "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts" -Kind "Storage" -AccountType "Standard_RAGRS"
```

Then I get the error:

> New-AzureRmResource : A parameter cannot be found that matches
>   parameter name 'AccountType'.

How do I pass this in?  I assume I am missing something easy here. Thank you.

**Answer thanks to the help below**

> $props = New-Object PSObject
>
> $props | add-member AccountType "Standard_RAGRS"
>
> $props | add-member Kind "Storage"
>
> New-AzureRmResource -Location "East US" -ResourceGroupName
>   "myResGrp" -ResourceName "storagename" -ResourceType
>   "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts" -Properties $props -ApiVersion
>   "2015-06-15"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the accountType into a hash table for parameter "Properties" (if  you are using 1.5.0, this is "PropertyObject"), and you should specify API version too. Here is an Example.

```
$properties = @{"AccountType"="Standard_RAGRS"}

New-AzureRmResource -Location "East US" `
                    -ResourceGroupName "myResGrp" `
                    -ResourceName "storagename" `
                    -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" `
                    -Properties $properties `
                    -ApiVersion "2015-06-15"
```

You need to specify API version because in the latest Azure PowerShell, by default, they are using 2016-03-30 for Storage Account, which has already changed AccountType to SKU, but the command `New-AzureRmResource` does not support SKU yet.

Comment: Awesome, this was it!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have AzureRM.Resources of version 2.0, it should support the latest properties you need to make this work. Prior to 2016-01-01 version of the api, SKU was called accountType, as the problem you're having.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt712701.aspx

Check the module version you're running:

```
 Get-Module  AzureRM.Resources
```

I'd recommend updating your AzureRM module, using Update-Module (assuming WMF5 installed and that you installed the AzureRM.Resources module in the firstplace using get-module/install-module).

If you cannot upgrade your AzureRM.Resources module; you can always specify the properties missing using -Properties @{ "AccountType"="Standard_RAGRS"}. You can also try using the New-AzureRmStorageAccount , it might have the properties you're looking for (as the cmdlet is under AzureRM.Storage, and could have a different version / subset).

Hope this helps!:)

Comment: Thank you!  I was at 1.0.4 - now I am at 1.5 which seems to be the most recent?  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/1.5.0 - still having problems.  Still nothing is working, even specifying the properties I get "New-AzureRmResource : AccountPropertyIsInvalid : Account property accountType is invalid for the request."  I have to use the New-AzureRmResource as I need resource groups.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have version 2.0.0 on my machine (installed from PSGallery). https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Resources/2.0.0 . You could also try the azure-sdk installer or the web gallery, it might give you a more recent version.